# How to save string in print format in python

Tags: python

I have a string that if I print it without 'print' function, it returns:

```
'WITH bucket_table AS (\nSELECT\nCASE\n\tWHEN var_1<0.50 THEN 0\n\tWHEN var_1>=0.50'
```

but if I use print(some_string):

```
WITH bucket_table AS (
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN var_1<0.50 THEN 0
    WHEN var_1>=0.50
```

How to save it in format that it would always be return as in 'print' format
so if I just enter in python cell:

some_string, it will return output as if I have entered print(some_string)

Comment: What do you mean by *print it without 'print' function*?

Comment: @Guy yes, without print function

Comment: Do you use ```repr(some_string)``` at the first?

Comment: because if i want so save it in print format to another variable, I cant do it @Guy

Comment: @artur: If it's already a `str`, just assign it to that other variable and call `print` when you print that other variable.

Comment: @artur this wasn't yes or no question, I asked for clarification.

Comment: @Guy I want it to be saved in a friendly format. so if I just call some_string, it will be printed is the same format as in print(some_string) format

Comment: Maybe `string.replace("\n", "\\n")`?

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about the automatic echo in the interactive interpreter? That's *intentionally* echoing the `repr` of the object, typically something programmatically useful that could be pasted back in to produce an equivalent object. And it has no effect whatsoever in actual scripts (there is no automatic echo anywhere but the interactive interpreter). **If you want to print the friendly form, call `print`.**

There are *terrible* ways to "fix" this (making a custom string-like class that implements `__repr__` in terms of `str`'s `__str__`), but don't do it. Just call `print` when you don't want quotes and escapes.